# CultureInfo.GetCultures returns different DateTimeSettings for specific culture than when using GetCultureInfo by Name or LCID

Tags: .net, cultureinfo, regional-settings

First I edit my regional settings and change the dateformat for the locale `nl-BE` to use `yyyy-MM-dd`.
[image]

Then in my ASP.NET code (Standard .Net 4.6.1 on a Windows 10 machine) I run this code:

```
CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.InstalledWin32Cultures)
```

The result of this is a list with cultures. When I specifically look at the locale that I changed (nl-BE) I get the following result:

[image: getcultures returns the modified locale settings]

This is the same as what I specified in my windows settings, pictured above, which seems fine.

If I, in the same application, search for this specific locale either by name or LCID, this customized setting is not displayed:

[image]

Can someone explain to me why there is a difference between the two?

Is there perhaps another key I can use to make sure I get the same result?

Comment: i suspect asp.net is not running as you, it is running as the machine account

Comment: @pm100 then why does CultureInfo.GetCultures return the correct result while running in the same process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor of the [`CultureInfo`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/cultureinfo.cs,382) class has a `Boolean` argument `useUserOverride` which specifies whether to apply the (regional) settings you set for your user profile *(which go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International` in the registry)*.

```
public CultureInfo(int culture) : this(culture, true) {}

public CultureInfo(int culture, bool useUserOverride) 
{
   // ...
}
```

> `useUserOverride`:
>   A Boolean that denotes whether to use the user-selected culture settings (true) or the default culture settings (false).

**[`CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes types)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/cultureinfo.cs,1056)** (via [`CultureData.GetCultures(CultureTypes types)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/culturedata.cs,1023)) creates instances using `true` (via the constructors default value).

```
cultures[i] = new CultureInfo(cultureNames[i]);
```

So these cultures have your changes.

**[`GetCultureInfo(int culture)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/cultureinfo.cs,1898)** instantiates a `CultureInfo` (using [`GetCurrentInfoHelper`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/cultureinfo.cs,1819)) passing `false` to `userUserOverride`:

```
retval = new CultureInfo(lcid, false);
```

This results in a returned `CultureInfo` without your changes.